# gcc -Wl,--exclude-libs,<library.a> is not working

Tags: gcc, symbols, ld

Im using gcc on Linux and creating a shared library for static libraries. I dont want symbols from some static libraries to be exported.

> gcc version is 4.8.0.

Im trying this option at `gcc` command and it's not working:

> -Wl,--exclude-libs,libabc.a .

If I use this option, it's removing all the symbols which not what I want.:

> -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL

Can somebody help in how to use `--exclude-option` and not to export symbols from specific static library, please?

Thanks
Chandra

Comment: From what i could see in `man ld`, it should be `-Wl,--exclude-libs,abc`

Comment: I tried core12 , libcore12 and libcore12.a...anything I give the symbol is seen in dynamic section . Im using "readelf --syms -D mylib.so" command.

Answer (score 6):

Please ignore my comment to question, it is incorrect.

Minimal example:

test1.c:

```
int testvar1;
int test1(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

test2.c:

```
extern int testvar1;
int test1(void);

int test2(void) {
    testvar1 = -1;
    return test1() + 2;
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *lib = dlopen("./libtest2.so", RTLD_NOW);
    int (*f)(void) = dlsym(lib, "test2");
    printf("%d\n", f());

    return 0;
}
```

Build:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -c test1.c
$ ar cru libtest1.a test1.o
$ gcc -fPIC -c test2.c
$ gcc -shared -o libtest2.so test2.o -L. -ltest1 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libtest1.a
$ gcc test.c -ldl
$ ./a.out
3
$ readelf --syms -D libtest2.so | grep test1
$
```

Comment: Hi Keltar, Example provided by u is working for removing function symbols. But wat I want is the remove symbol of a variable.

Comment: It is indeed. However, i don't see that it hides even with `--exclude-libs ALL`, so it could be intended. The only way i see to achieve what you want is to either mark this variables as hidden manually (via `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`) or by compiling your `.a` with `-fvisibility=hidden` to automatically mark all symbols as hidden.

Comment: Problem is the archive file Im using is a 3rd party library where I cannot change the code to make it hidden. I just need to use that .a file and create and so file removing some symbols.  BTW, --exclude-libs ALL is working in my case and removing all the symbols for so file which is not wat I want.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please confirm that this given example (already modified to include variable too) produces mentioned results with exclude `ALL`? Because it doesn't in my case, testvar1 is still not hidden and i'm not sure it should be.

Comment: With your example exclude ALL is not working. But with my project its working and removing almost all symbols.

Comment: Hi Keltar, Is there any command similar to objcopy which can remove symbol from shared objects files. ?

Comment: @Chandu I doubt you can just remove symbol and don't break things in process, because if it is in library - there is a reason for that, like it is being used from somewhere. But `objcopy -L symbolname` could mark it hidden (same thing as `__attiribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` or `-fvisibility=hidden`). Your latest question already contains an answer, so i'm not sure i get it.

Comment: Kelter, Im sure that this is not used anywhere else. Its exported as it is global variable. objcopy is removing symbol from .o and .a files but not .so file.

Comment: Well, objcopy does work with shared libraries, but it can modify only normal symbol table, not dynamic one - because it's much more than just removing something, it could affect addresses, etc.. Depending on your specifics (or not yours - who knows where your static library comes from), you could try removing this symbol from .a with `objcopy -N your_unneeded_variable lib1.a lib1_modified.a`.